# How to write an efficient wrapper for data wrangling, allowing to turn off any wrapped part when calling the wrapper

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, wrapper, data-wrangling

To streamline data wrangling, I write a wrapper function consisted of several "verb functions" that process the data. Each one performs one task on the data. However, not all tasks are applicable to all datasets that pass through this process, and sometimes, for certain data, I might want to switch off *some* "verb functions", and skip them.

I'm trying to understand whether there's a conventional/canonical way to build such workflow within a wrapper function in R. Importantly, a way that will be *efficient*, both performance-wise and concise code.

### Example

As part of data wrangling, I want to carry out several steps:

1. Clean up column headers (using `janitor::clean_names()`)
2. Recode values in the data, such that `TRUE` and `FALSE` are replaced with `1` and `0` (using `gsub()`).
3. Recode string values to lowercase (using `tolower()`).
4. Pivot wider based on specific `id` column (using `tidyr::pivot_wider`)
5. Drop rows with `NA` values (using `dplyr::drop_na()`)

***Toy data***

```r
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(2021)

# simulate data
df <-
  data.frame(id = 1:20,
           isMale = rep(c("true", "false"), times = 10),
           WEIGHT = sample(50:100, 20),
           hash_Numb = stri_rand_strings(20, 5)) %>%
  cbind(., score = sample(200:800, size = 20))

# sprinkle NAs randomly
df[c("isMale", "WEIGHT", "hash_Numb", "score")] <-
  lapply(df[c("isMale", "WEIGHT", "hash_Numb", "score")], function(x) {
    x[sample(seq_along(x), 0.25 * length(x))] <- NA
    x
  })


df <- 
  df %>%
  tidyr::expand_grid(., Condition = c("A","B"))

df
#> # A tibble: 40 x 6
#>       id isMale WEIGHT hash_Numb score Condition
#>    <int> <chr>   <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>    
#>  1     1 <NA>       56 EvRAq        NA A        
#>  2     1 <NA>       56 EvRAq        NA B        
#>  3     2 false      87 <NA>        322 A        
#>  4     2 false      87 <NA>        322 B        
#>  5     3 true       95 13pXe       492 A        
#>  6     3 true       95 13pXe       492 B        
#>  7     4 <NA>       88 4WMBS       626 A        
#>  8     4 <NA>       88 4WMBS       626 B        
#>  9     5 true       NA Nrl1W       396 A        
#> 10     5 true       NA Nrl1W       396 B        
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The data shows test scores of 20 people who took a test under two conditions. For each person we also know the gender (`isMale`), the weight in kilograms(`WEIGHT`), and a unique `hash_number`.

***Data cleanup and wrangling***

Before this data is sent to analysis, it needs to be cleaned up, according to a certain chain of steps, which I laid out above.

```r
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

# helper function
convert_true_false_to_1_0 <- function(x) {
  
  first_pass <- gsub("^(?:TRUE)$", 1, x, ignore.case = TRUE)
  gsub("^(?:FALSE)$", 0, first_pass, ignore.case = TRUE)
}

# chain of steps
df %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), tolower)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = condition, values_from = score) %>%
  drop_na()
```

**My Question: *How to pack this process in a wrapper that allows to flexibly switch some steps off?***

One idea I have in my mind is to use a `%>%` pipe with conditionals such as:

```r
my_wrangling_wrapper <- function(dat,
                                 clean_names       = TRUE, 
                                 convert_tf_to_1_0 = TRUE, 
                                 convert_to_lower  = TRUE, 
                                 pivot_widr        = TRUE,
                                 drp_na            = TRUE){
  dat %>%
    {if (clean_names)       janitor::clean_names(.)                                     else .} %>%
    {if (convert_tf_to_1_0) mutate(., across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0))  else .} %>%
    {if (convert_to_lower)  mutate(., across(everything(), tolower))                    else .} %>%
    {if (pivot_widr)        pivot_wider(., names_from = condition, values_from = score) else .} %>%
    {if (drp_na)            drop_na(.)                                                  else .}
}
```

This way, all steps are defaulted to happen, unless turned off:

- **Use-case #1 -- Default run:**

```r
> my_wrangling_wrapper(dat = df)

## # A tibble: 6 x 6
##   id    is_male weight hash_numb a     b    
##   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
## 1 3     1       95     13pxe     492   492  
## 2 9     1       54     hgzxp     519   519  
## 3 12    0       72     vwetc     446   446  
## 4 15    1       52     qadxc     501   501  
## 5 17    1       71     g42vg     756   756  
## 6 18    0       80     qiejd     712   712
```

- **Use-case #2 -- Don't convert `true`/`false` to `1`/`0` and don't drop `NA`s:**

```r
> my_wrangling_wrapper(dat = df, convert_tf_to_1_0 = FALSE, drp_na = FALSE)

## # A tibble: 20 x 6
##    id    is_male weight hash_numb a     b    
##    <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
##  1 1     NA      56     evraq     NA    NA   
##  2 2     false   87     NA        322   322  
##  3 3     true    95     13pxe     492   492  
##  4 4     NA      88     4wmbs     626   626  
##  5 5     true    NA     nrl1w     396   396  
##  6 6     false   NA     4oq74     386   386  
##  7 7     true    NA     gg23f     NA    NA   
##  8 8     false   94     NA        NA    NA   
##  9 9     true    54     hgzxp     519   519  
## 10 10    false   97     NA        371   371  
## 11 11    true    90     NA        768   768  
## 12 12    false   72     vwetc     446   446  
## 13 13    NA      NA     jkhjh     338   338  
## 14 14    false   NA     0swem     778   778  
## 15 15    true    52     qadxc     501   501  
## 16 16    false   75     NA        219   219  
## 17 17    true    71     g42vg     756   756  
## 18 18    false   80     qiejd     712   712  
## 19 19    NA      68     tadad     NA    NA   
## 20 20    NA      53     iyw3o     NA    NA
```

---

### My problem

Although the solution I came up with *does work*, I've learned that relying on the pipe operator is not advised within functions, because it slows down the process ([see reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933272/why-is-using-dplyr-pipe-slower-than-an-equivalent-non-pipe-expression-for)). Also, since `%>%` is not part of `base R`, there has to be a way to achieve the same "tweakable wrapping" functionality without the pipe. So I wonder: is there a conventional way to write a wrapper function that could be tweaked to turn off some of its components, and still overall remain performance-efficient?

{It's worth mentioning that [I've asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65722125/6105259) regarding building a wrapper for `ggplot`, turning `geoms` off as desired. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65761258/6105259) was great but not applicable to the current question.}

Comment: Can you check the output of `my_wrangling_wrapper(dat = df)` I get different results when I redo your code.

Comment: @thothal, you're totally correct. I guess I printed it without the correct seed number. I updated the post now. Could you confirm you get the same output?

Comment: Yes, I almost tripped over that ;)

Comment: FYI the pipe operator is now much much faster than at the time of linked post, something like x100. And even before that it shouldn't have been a concerned for data wrangling where each operation is much more expensive than a pipe call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staying with `%>%`, you could create a [functional sequence](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/fseq.html):

```
library(magrittr)

my_wrangling_wrapper =
  . %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), tolower)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = condition, values_from = score) %>%
  drop_na()
```

As this sequence behaves like a list, you can decide which steps to use by selecting the elements:

```
clean_names       = TRUE
convert_tf_to_1_0 = TRUE 
convert_to_lower  = FALSE 
pivot_widr        = FALSE
drp_na            = TRUE

my_wrangling_wrapper[c(clean_names,
                       convert_tf_to_1_0,
                       convert_to_lower,
                       pivot_widr,
                       drp_na)]

#Functional sequence with the following components:
#
# 1. janitor::clean_names(.)
# 2. mutate(., across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0))
# 3. drop_na(.)

df %>% my_wrangling_wrapper[c(clean_names,
                               convert_tf_to_1_0,
                               convert_to_lower,
                               pivot_widr,
                               drp_na)]()

#  id is_male weight hash_numb score
#1  1       1     51     Zm1Xx   343
#2  3       1     99     Xc2rm   703
#3  6       0     62     2r2cP   243
#4 12       0     84     llI0f   297
#5 16       0     72     AO76M   475
#6 18       0     63     zGJmW   376
```

Without `%>%`, you could use the equivalent `freduce` solution:

```
clean_names  <- function(x) janitor::clean_names(x,dat)   

convert_tf_to_1_0 <- function(x) mutate(x,dat, across(everything(),
                                               convert_true_false_to_1_0)) 

convert_to_lower <- function(x) mutate(x,dat, across(everything(), tolower))
         
pivot_widr <- function(x) pivot_wider(x,dat, names_from = condition,
                                             values_from = score) 

drp_na <- function(x) drop_na(x, dat) 

my_wrangling_list <- list(clean_names, convert_tf_to_1_0, drp_na)
magrittr::freduce(df, my_wrangling_list)
```

Or with `%>%` and `freduce`:

```
df %>% freduce(my_wrangling_list)
```

I wouldn't be too concerned by the piping overhead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50138419/13513328) in the link you referenced : when comparing milliseconds, piping has an impact, but when it comes to bigger calculations, piping overhead becomes negligible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use closures to achieve the same as the functional sequence illustrated in the @Waldi answer. Something like:

```
#we build a wrapper generator providing an arbitrary number of functions to apply
wrapperGenerator<-function(...) {
    flist<-list(...)
    function(data, conf = rep(TRUE, length(flist))) {
        if (!is.logical(conf) || (length(conf)!=length(flist)))
            stop("Wrong conf")
        for (i in seq_along(flist)) {
            if (conf[[i]])
                data<-flist[[i]](data)  
        }
        data
    }
}

#An example for string manipulation
wg<-wrapperGenerator(tolower, function(x) paste0(x,"_suff"), function(x) substring(x,1,5))

#some usage
require(stringi)
set.seed(1)
data<-stri_rand_strings(10,10)
data
#[1] "GNZuCtwed3" "CAgNlUizNm" "vDe7GN0NrL" "TbUBpfn6iP" "oemYWm1Tjg"
#[6] "TrRF46JWfP" "uISKeFTl5s" "LqLKTtrOmx" "QiOKkCi7F8" "E3dsmnSPob"

#Full pipeline
wg(data)
#[1] "gnzuc" "cagnl" "vde7g" "tbubp" "oemyw" "trrf4" "uiske" "lqlkt" "qiokk"
#[10] "e3dsm"

#Just the first two steps
wg(data,c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
# [1] "gnzuctwed3_suff" "cagnluiznm_suff" "vde7gn0nrl_suff" "tbubpfn6ip_suff"
# [5] "oemywm1tjg_suff" "trrf46jwfp_suff" "uiskeftl5s_suff" "lqlkttromx_suff"
# [9] "qiokkci7f8_suff" "e3dsmnspob_suff"
```

EDIT

Adding a few comments about how the above works. The `wrapperGenerator` is a function that returns a function and it's built just by providing the functions you want to wrap. No data is needed here. The value of `wrapperGenerator` is itself a function (`wg` in the example) that you can apply to the actual data. By providing the additional `conf` argument to this function, you tell which steps are to be performed.

Closures are a very powerful tool in R. [Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) you find a must read on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining how `wrapperGenerator()` understands what is the data and what are the functions? It accepts just `...` so I don't follow where the distinction is made.

Answer (score 1):

I would (as @Nicola) use [closures](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/fp.html) but with (IMHO) slightly cleaner interface:

```r
function_factory <- function(...) {
   all_fns <- list(...)
   ## ... arguments must be named
   stopifnot(!is.null(names(all_fns)))
   function(x, ...) {
      selected_fns <- rev(as.character(rlang::ensyms(...)))
      ## if nothing was selected chose everything
      if (!length(selected_fns)) {
         selected_fns <- rev(names(all_fns))
      }
      stopifnot(all(selected_fns %in% names(all_fns)))
      ## function compose operator
      `%.%` <- function(f1, f2) function(...) f1(f2(...))
      fn_seq <- Reduce(`%.%`, all_fns[selected_fns])
      fn_seq(x)
   }
}

## define all potential functions via named(!) arguments to funciton_factory
fn_f <- function_factory(multiply_by_1000 = function(x) x * 1000,
                         make_negative    = function(x) -abs(x),
                         add_100          = function(x) x + 100)

## example with vector as input
x <- 1:10

## to apply a selected subset simply provide the names of the chunks
fn_f(x, add_100)
fn_f(x, multiply_by_1000, make_negative)
## order matters
fn_f(x, add_100, make_negative)
fn_f(x, make_negative, add_100)

## example with data.frame as input
library(dplyr)
m2 <- mtcars
m2 <- m2 %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), .fns = function(x) {
      x[sample(length(x), 5)] <- NA
      x
   }))
fn_fd <- function_factory(replace_nas = function(data) mutate(data, across(everything(), .fns = coalesce, -1)),
                          round       = function(data) mutate(data, across(where(is.double), .fns = round, 0)),
                          append_new  = function(data) mutate(data, across(c(vs, am), .fns = paste0, "_new")))
fn_fd(m2, replace_nas, round)
fn_fd(m2, replace_nas, append_new, round)
fn_fd(m2, replace_nas, round, append_new)

## toy example from OP
toy_f <- function_factory(clean_names = clean_names,
                          convert_0_1 = function(x) mutate(x, across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0)),
                          to_lower    = function(x) mutate(x, across(everything(), tolower)),
                          pivot       = function(x) pivot_wider(x, names_from = condition, values_from = score),
                          dropna      = drop_na)

## do all
toy_f(df)
## everything but conversion and dropping
toy_f(df, clean_names, to_lower, pivot)
```

### Explanation

- `function_factory` is a `closure`, i.e. it stores all named(!) arguments in `all_fns` and returns a **`function`**. The idea is that this function now can access `all_fns` and do its magic.
- The returned function uses also `...` to see which elements we want to use (the `rlang::ensyms` part is syntacic sugar, because with this approach we can specify the names of the functions without quotes)
- Then, we compose all selected functions into one function using `Reduce`, which *successively combines the elements of a given vector* [1] (this could also be done via `purrr::compose`)
- Eventually we apply the composed function to our data and  *voilà*

---

[1] [`?Reduce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/funprog)

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed clear to understand. Would you say that essentially `function_factory()` is equivalent to `magrittr::freduce()` in terms of functionality?

Comment: Did not know `freduce` before, but I guess you can get the same results with it, Define a global list of all functions, and then use `freduce` with only a subset will get you to the same result. The choice should then be made on code readability (which is to some extent a subjetcive choice) and the question if one wants to add another library: `freduce(df, my_fns[c("name1, "name2)])` vs `factory(df, name1, name2)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be

```
my_wrangling_wrapper <- function(dat,
                                 clean_names       = TRUE, 
                                 convert_tf_to_1_0 = TRUE, 
                                 convert_to_lower  = TRUE, 
                                 pivot_widr        = TRUE,
                                 drp_na            = TRUE){
  

  if (clean_names)       dat <- janitor::clean_names(dat)                                     
  if (convert_tf_to_1_0) dat <- mutate(dat, across(everything(), convert_true_false_to_1_0))  
  if (convert_to_lower)  dat <- mutate(dat, across(everything(), tolower))                    
  if (pivot_widr)        dat <- pivot_wider(dat, names_from = condition, values_from = score) 
  if (drp_na)            dat <- drop_na(dat)                                                  
  dat 
}
```